# Spark: Read Iterate on 2 files

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata, apache-spark

I need some help about Spark+Java programming.
This is my issue:

I have a big file in hdfs, called A and an other big one called B.
Basically, I need to iterate on the first one (A) and the second one (B) at the same moment.
I mean something like that (This is pseudocode):

```
a = read.A; //Read record from A
b = read.B; // Read record from B
while( a != EOF )
{
   if ( a > b)
   {
        b= read.B;
        // Write Output in some way
   }
   else
   {
      a= read.A;
       //Write output in some way
   }

}
```

Is possibile to do something like that using Spark+Java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do that with Apache Spark, but **you shouldn't**.

Map Reduce frameworks like Spark, Hadoop, etc. were invented to split a big task into several smaller ones, which could be executed in parallel. There isn't any guarantee about the order in which the tasks will be processed, because the speed advantage partially is based on the fact that the worker nodes don't have to synchronize state.

Your problem doesn't fit because:

- It needs to know the last read value (alternately retrieved from A or B). That's a shared state.
- You cannot parallize the read steps because you can't know in advance if you have to read A or B.

If you need a performance boost, you have to look somewhere else. Try to figure out what's the bottleneck (memory, disk access, ...).

Comment: The output of the Join will be a set of elments where the first row of A is together with the first row of B and so on?

Comment: Ok. My issue is that I am not interested in equal join. As you can note taking a look at my pseudo-code.
I am interested in iterating on 2 files and some time holding a tuple from file A and keeping iterating on file B and viceversa.

Comment: I need to iterate over them and find out and when A is > B holding A and keeping iterating on B until A < B and in that time writing an output for each record.
I can not process sequentially on them, because I need high performance.

Comment: If spark is not right for this stuff, there is other tools on Hadoop to do that?

Comment: @Edge7: Ok, that's a sequential algorithm, no Map Reduce framework will support that, because they were invented to parallelize tasks. Instead you could have a look at [Terracotta](http://terracotta.org/), which allows huge amount of in-memory calculations (but I don't have experience with it).

Comment: Maybe, Could I use collect to get B file? Then iterate on A using forEach Function and a normal loop for iterate on B?

Comment: @Edge7: I completely rewrote my answer to reflect our discussion and cleaned up comments. Let me know if something's missing.